# css border not showing but css is applied

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to apply a border to all `tr`'s in a `thead`.

**Css(stylus):**

```
table
    thead
        tr
          border: solid #000;
          border-width: 0 10px;
```

According to chrome the styles get applied, but the border doesn't actually show up:
[image]

Comment: link:-http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody

Comment: Try applying to `table` or `td`. Does that work?

Comment: `tr` need its `table` to have `border-collapse: collapse` for border to work ... and when that can't be used, set it on the `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` need its `table` to have `border-collapse: collapse` for border to work

```css
table.first {
    border-collapse: separate;     /*  property default  */
}
table.second {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead tr {
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

/*  for this demo only  */
div {
  margin: 25px 20px 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>This table's tr (in thead) has no border</div>

<table class="first">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Left Head</td>
      <td>Right Head</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Left</td>
      <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>This table's tr (in thead) has border</div>

<table class="second">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Left Head</td>
      <td>Right Head</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Left</td>
      <td>Right</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
thead {color:green;}
tbody {color:blue;}
tfoot {color:red;}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a css master but i usually write border properties in one line:

```
border: 10px solid #000;
```